# How could I successfully implement an upsert function with Ecto?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I'm trying to implement an `upsert/2` function to my entities on a Phoenix context. For example I'll show only one schema.

Firstly, here's the migration for the `tag` table:

```
defmodule Pescarte.Repo.Migrations.CriaTag do
  use Ecto.Migration

  def up do
    create table(:tag) do
      add :etiqueta, :string, null: false
      add :id_publico, :string

      add :categoria_id, references(:categoria), null: false

      timestamps()
    end

    create unique_index(:tag, [:etiqueta])
    create index(:tag, [:categoria_id])

    alter table(:midia) do
      remove :tags
    end
  end

  def down do
    drop_if_exists table(:tag)
    drop_if_exists unique_index(:tag, [:etiqueta])
    drop_if_exists index(:tag, [:categoria_id])

    alter table(:midia) do
      add :tags, {:array, :string}, null: false
    end
  end
end
```

And now this is the schema built with ecto:

```
defmodule Pescarte.Domains.ModuloPesquisa.Models.Midia.Tag do
  use Pescarte, :model

  alias Pescarte.Domains.ModuloPesquisa.Models.Midia.Categoria

  @type t :: %Tag{id: integer, etiqueta: binary, id_publico: binary, categoria: Categoria.t()}

  @required_fields ~w(etiqueta categoria_id)a

  schema "tag" do
    field :etiqueta, :string
    field :id_publico, Pescarte.Types.PublicId, autogenerate: true

    belongs_to :categoria, Categoria

    timestamps()
  end

  @spec changeset(map) :: {:ok, Tag.t()} | {:error, changeset}
  def changeset(tag \\ %__MODULE__{}, attrs) do
    tag
    |> cast(attrs, @required_fields)
    |> validate_required(@required_fields)
    |> unique_constraint(:etiqueta)
    |> foreign_key_constraint(:categoria_id)
    |> apply_action(:parse)
  end
end
```

And finally, my current `upsert/2` implementation, which receives in the first optional argument the current schema and then their attributes! For a newly insertion, I omit the first argument with fallbacks for a default schema with `nil` fields. For updates, I pass the current schema in the first argument and newly attributes to update:

```
defmodule Pescarte.Domains.ModuloPesquisa.Repository do
  @behaviour IManageRepository

  defp on_conflict do
    {:replace_all_except, [:id, :id_publico]}
  end

  @impl true
  def upsert_tag(tag \\ %Tag{}, attrs) do
    with {:ok, tag} <- Tag.changeset(tag, attrs) do
      Repo.insert(tag, on_conflict: on_conflict(), conflict_target: [:etiqueta])
    end
  end
end
```

The above implementation works on insert statements, however when I try to update an existing tag, I receive this PK error:

```bash
** (Ecto.ConstraintError) constraint error when attempting to insert struct:

    * "tag_pkey" (unique_constraint)

If you would like to stop this constraint violation from raising an
exception and instead add it as an error to your changeset, please
call `unique_constraint/3` on your changeset with the constraint
`:name` as an option.

The changeset has not defined any constraint.

    (ecto 3.10.1) lib/ecto/repo/schema.ex:804: anonymous fn/4 in Ecto.Repo.Schema.constraints_to_errors/3
    (elixir 1.14.2) lib/enum.ex:1658: Enum."-map/2-lists^map/1-0-"/2
    (ecto 3.10.1) lib/ecto/repo/schema.ex:788: Ecto.Repo.Schema.constraints_to_errors/3
    (ecto 3.10.1) lib/ecto/repo/schema.ex:769: Ecto.Repo.Schema.apply/4
    (ecto 3.10.1) lib/ecto/repo/schema.ex:377: anonymous fn/15 in Ecto.Repo.Schema.do_insert/4
```

What it really means? The `:on_conflict` option didn't resolves already?

Comment: What it really means is the `tags` table has a unique constraint on its primary key field, which is called `id`. The primary key `id` in a database table is always unique.
The main problem with your code is you are using `Repo.insert` to try and update a thing. Look at this: https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Repo.html#c:update/2

Comment: @PeacefulJames not really, see the `upserts` section of the `insert` docs: https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Repo.html#c:insert/2-upserts

Comment: Not sure, but what happens if you add `:id` to `conflict_target`?

Comment: I think you could just turn `etiqueta` into the primary_key and that way it should work, unless it's that important for you to save space.

Or maybe try just updating the categoria_id as it looks to me that it's the only thing you would want to update. `{:replace, [:categoria_id]}`.

I also wonder if it could be possible that you already had duplicated rows before having the unique constraint? (Probably not)

Comment: @AdamMillerchip adding `:id` to `conflict_target` seems to tell postgresql to search for a composite unique index for `:id` and `:etiqueta`